# Reloading imageView

Tags: ios, image, imageview

How can I do it?
I draw image on image inside imageView with UIImageView category, then I set new image, I use all

```
 – setNeedsDisplay
 – layoutSubviews
 – setNeedsLayout
-  layoutIfNeeded
```

and simple setting image not helps too..

```
 self.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-black.png"];
```

but it not reloads

Comment: You need to show more code. The obvious things to check are that you have not added myImage (assumed to be a UIImageView) as a subview or that it is not positioned within the visible area. Another common problem is that your image exists but it is not added to the project so it can't be found by imageNamed. If you are seeing one image but cannot change it, ensure that you are actually setting the image again and that the image you are changing it to is in fact different in appearance.

Comment: Log self.myImage and see if it's nil.